# Convert HTML page into MS word using java

Tags: java, javascript, html, ms-word

I want to convert a HTML page into MS word.
I want to know what API's will be helpful and also if there is any other option to do the same.
The entire page is to be converted into .doc (eg. If there is a table in the html page, a similar table  must be created in the word doc)
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: That is not easy.  What is the source of your web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the Apache POI library ... http://poi.apache.org/ it has read / write support for all of the Office products, from the site :

> In short, you can read and write MS Excel files using Java. In
>   addition, you can read and write MS Word and MS PowerPoint files using
>   Java.

Used it a lot for Excel and very simple to pick up and use.

Note ... the Apache POI library doesnt convert HTML to DOC(x) but it does allow you to write in the format - ie you would have to do the formatting yourself

Comment: Thats the problem, i want a completely formatted word doc. My htmp page has many tables in it and I need those in the word doc.